# I want to hide myself from a particular friend's friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I guess this is a special case but I want to hide my profile, especially DP (Profile Picture) and timeline, from a particular friend's friends.

I know we can hide ourselves from friends of friends. But I want do it for a particular friend's friends only.

Comment: If you're patient enough you can block one by one.

Comment: @pnuts - Correct, I do not want to unfriend that friend.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That is a good idea, but it does not take care of people whom my friend will add in future. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

1. Block that specific person.
2. Try to keep an eye at your friend's friend list, Regularly block the ones whom you don't like.
3. If you are too much concern to whom he/she in future might make friends just unfriend and block him/her too.
4. Why not just remove the Profile Picture? Change it to whatever you like. Except the one which is creating the issue.